# Completely delete the object in Amazon S3 after a certain period of time after the delete marker is assigned to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have versioning enabled the S3 bucket.
I want to completely delete an object after a certain period of time after the object has been given a delete marker.
Is it possible to do this using lifecycle rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve this by using two S3 Lifecycle rules:

- **Permanently delete previous versions of objects**, for which you can specify "Number of days after objects become previous versions". I presume that deleting an object, which places a Delete Marker on the object, effectively makes the 'current' version (prior to Deletion) become a 'previous' version.
- **Delete expired delete markers or incomplete multipart uploads**, which should then deleting the 'solo' Delete Marker.

I haven't tried that combination, so I recommend some testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However, doesn't your approach also delete the older versions of objects that do not have a delete marker?
I want to delete only the objects with the delete marker without affecting the other objects.

Comment: Ah! Yes, you're probably correct. In that case, you'd need to write your own code to loop through the objects and perform this logic.